# Why does my overlay normal distribution curve does not touch x-axis?

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

I have a histograms to visualize distribution, of interval data. I want to overlay a smooth normal distribution curve. The line does not go all the way down to touch the x-axis as highlited with the red box. Another concern I have with this is that the very left bar should not be less than 0.5. Some of the bar resides below 0.5 as shown in the blue box. My lowest data value is 0.58.

```
g <- dataset$NEW_CASE_FATALITY_RATE

h <- hist(g # depandant variable (case_fatality_rate)
, main = "Histogram - Case Fatality Rate" # chart title
, xlab = "Case Fatality Rate"
,ylab = "f"
,col = "#f0ffff"
,xlim = c(0.0,2.5)
,ylim = c(0.0,12)

)



xfit <- seq(min(g), max(g), length = 51) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(g), sd = sd(g)) 
yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(g) 

lines(xfit, yfit, col = "black", lwd = 2)

grid(nx = NA, ny = NULL,
     lty = 1, col = "gray", lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Because you only plot it from `min(g)` to `max(g)`. Why would it be close to 0 where you still have data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you would want to do about the bar being at 0.5. A histogram breaks continuous data into bins—it doesn't necessarily adhere to your exact values. You can work to set bins how you want, but it kind of defeats the purpose to say no bins can go below some value if that's where your values are.

Comment: @GregorThomas It is just that when I googled images of a normal distribution curve I see the line touching the x-axis. Also, I saw a similar pattern in youtube tutorials. so is my graph normal distribution correct?

Comment: Yeah, you just chopped off the tails.

Comment: You can extend the range, something like `width <- diff(range(g))` and then use `xfit <- seq(min(g) - 0.1 * width, max(g) + 0.1 * width, length = 51)`, extending the length of the normal curve by 10% on each end.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks.